# How to return an ArrayList for a search method which includes a switch statement

Tags: java, for-loop, search, arraylist, switch-statement

I have only been coding for three months so forgive me if this is a silly question or I am getting things totally wrong. I have a method to search through an ArrayList of books. The method should return a new ArrayList of all books with a specified genre. I have a Enums class BookGenre, and am trying to use a switch  statement within an enhanced for loop to add books to the list. I get back a list which includes the names of all books instead of just the comedy ones. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

Book book1 = new Book("Book one", BookGenre.COMEDY);
        Book book2 = new Book("Book two", BookGenre.THRILLER);
        Book book3 = new Book("Book three", BookGenre.THRILLER);

ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        books.add(book1);
        books.add(book2);
        books.add(book3);

//search by genre
ArrayList<Book> booksByGenre = searchByGenre(books, BookGenre.COMEDY);
        
        for (Book book : booksByGenre) {
            System.out.println(book.getName());
        }
}
```

```
public static ArrayList<Book> searchByGenre(ArrayList<Book> books,
            BookGenre genre) {
        ArrayList<Book> searchList = new ArrayList<Book>();

        for (Book book : books) {
            switch (genre) {
            case COMEDY:
                searchList.add(book);
                break;
            case THRILLER:
                searchList.add(book);
                break;
            }

        }
        return searchList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: you should compare the input `genre` to that of each `book` in the loop in `searchByGenre`, and add to the list only if they match.  Not sure that `switch` statement is applicable for this task of filtering at all.

Comment: I think the switch case could be confusing you. This looks easier to do with plain if's and else's and it should show you were you're going wrong. Right now the switch might look like its comparing, when really it just looks at the case and adds it regardless of case.

Comment: Look at your current switch statement.  You have two cases: one for comedy, and one for thriller.  Great.  What does the code do differently for each one?  Think about it, if the code does the same thing no matter which case is selected, is the switch-case statement really doing anything?  What construct could you use instead of a switch-case?  Hint: Think `if` statement

Comment: perhaps a certain getter/variable of the Book class should be used by book..

Comment: Remove the switch and use: if (book.genre == genre). If true, add to list.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Book` should have a `getGenre` method, maybe not named quite like this, but a method that returns its `BookGenre` to the caller. Then for each book (that is, in your enhanced `for` loop) if the book’s genre equals the genre searched for, add it to `searchList`, otherwise don’t. You will need an `if` statement, not a `switch`-`case` statement.

For comparison it’s a matter of taste whether you want to use `book.getGenre().equals(genre)` or `book.getGenre() == genre`. Be warned and take notice that the second form only works for enums, not for other objects. It works for enums because the compiler guarantees that there is only one instance of each enum constant. The first form works for all kinds of objects (also enums).

> … so forgive me if this is a silly question or I am getting things
> totally wrong.

It’s a good question and I don’t think you got things completely wrong. Your way of thinking could be improved a bit, though, that’s why you’re a learner (and we all are, or should at least be). While the `switch` statement *could* be made to work, it’s not a good idea to use it here. One, it’s easier to treat all genres the same: compare it to the genre of each book. Many real-life programs have stopped working correctly because they used `switch` on enums and one day a third enum constant was added that wasn’t in the `switch` statement and hence was not taking into account.